# Android 2.3.3 (Windows) emulator doesn't show the phone desktop on startup. Getting a repeated Launcher (com.android.launcher) error

Tags: android, windows, emulation, launcher

When I try to run the Android 2.3.3 emulator, the phone desktop doesn't show.

Instead, this error message keeps popping up :

```
The Application Launcher (process com.android.launcher) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
```

I keep force-closing it but it just keeps popping up.

However, any application that I try to run (I'm using Eclipse Helios for my IDE) runs fine in the background.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

you could look into the console view in eclipse.

or you could call

```
platform-tools/adb catlog
```

to display the java log.