# OutOfMemory on both device and emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, out-of-memory

I am getting OutOfMemory Exception while running my project on both emulator and device(acer tablet and samsung galaxy) showing

> the application launcher process `com.android.launcher` has stopped unexpectedly.

I've increase the virtual machine size of emulator to 256mb still there was no change in that exception. How can I avoid this exception?  And how can I increase the process size of the heap for both emulator and device?

Please refer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043901/android-2-3-3-windows-emulator-doesn't-show-the-phone-desktop-on-startup-getti)

Comment: can it be that it's specifically related to your project ? what do you do that you get out of memory exception ? what's the stacktrace ?

Comment: Could the cause be in your project? If yes, then you might have to disclose more details what the project does and perhaps try to find pieces of code that might be responsible for the behaviour. Have you tried to find if an even larger vm size could handle the project?

Comment: When i run my application...i am getting out of memory and if i force close this i can normally run the application...even in the middle of the application also i am getting this error.

Comment: @Aleksi i've increased the vm heap for emulator...i dont know how to increase the heap size in the device.

Comment: I'd suggest that you run your program with a relatively low vm memory size and take a memory dump on failure.

Comment: Please stop flagging to inform moderators that nobody has answered your question.

Comment: Are you using Bitmaps in your application?

Comment: Felt like, where do i shoot its dark when i read this question. please add some more info to your question, (code/stack-trace). or else you will end up wasting your bounty.

Comment: @joru yes i am using bitmaps in my application...

Comment: show me your code.. if you have a listview.. show me it's adapter's code

Comment: You might not be cleaning out Bitmaps. If you are storing them, you need to use bitmap.recycle() to tag them for garbage collection.

Comment: So many guesses in all directions.. Knowing what your application does and looking at some code will probably help us make the right guess. This is not a common issue so please add details about your application; What it does primarily, and atleast the `onCreate` code of your main activity.

Comment: @Peerke has the right answer.  There are tools to help you find the problems in your code.  You need to use those tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what kind of application you are running, but it's possible that you have a memory leak in your application. Then it would not matter how big you set your virtual machine size.

Check out the video below on how to find memory leaks in your own application. Works on devices and emulators. (I found a very big memory leak last week, that I didn't know I had in the application)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk&feature=player_embedded

Comment: The presentation in the video is very useful - the guy doing it is on the Android team at Google (the talk is from Google IO).  The parts about the memory analysis tool are really good.

Comment: As far as I know it's the only easy way to find memory leaks in your application. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing something extreme and actually need lots of memory, you shouldn't have to resort to increasing the memory footprint.  The bug that's causing this will probably run over any additional memory you give it.

Take a closer look at what comes before the out-of-memory error.  I recently saw that one because I caused an endless configuration change loop.  The only thing that stopped that endless loop was running out of memory.

While the few lines above the error looked fine, I realized that the number of log entries was much higher than normal, because it ran through the initialization for my activity repeatedly.

Your issue may be different, but I'm fairly sure that increasing the heap size won't fix it.